Why are Plans serialized explicitly in RetrieveRequest and SearchRequest (internal proto)
The proto definitions for RetrieveRequest and SearchRequest store the search/query plan in the following form:
// milvus/internal/proto/internal.proto
message RetrieveRequest {
  ...
  bytes serialized_expr_plan = 6;
  ...
}

The other alternative would be embed the PlanNode object directly in the RetrieveRequest, avoiding the need for explicit Marshal/Unmarshal:
message RetrieveRequest {
  ...
  plan.PlanNode plan = 6;
  ...
}

Why is the first version (explicit marshaling) preferred over the second?

The reason is:
SearchRequest is created by proxy node, and passed to the shard leader node, finally passed to a worker query node. Only the worker query node decodes the serialized_expr_plan.
If we use the second approach, the 'plan' will be encoded/decoded twice.
